# Random crash in iOS at AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue

Tags: ios, crash

**Error Message**

```
0 Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000c raw

0       libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 5 performSelector:withObject:

7       UIKit   -[UIViewController dealloc] + 1798

8 Cxxxxxx       AFQueryStringPairsFromKeyAndValue + 7759031

9       libsystem_blocks.dylib  _Block_release + 216

10 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_after_timer_callback + 66

11 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_client_callout + 22

12 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 2042

13 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_source_invoke + 738

14 libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 394

15 CoreFoundation       __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8

16 CoreFoundation       __CFRunLoopRun + 1590

17 CoreFoundation       CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516

18 CoreFoundation       CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108 

19 GraphicsServices     GSEventRunModal + 160

20      UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 144 

21      Cxxxxxxx        main.m line 15 main

22 libdyld.dylib        start + 2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Ideally, you need to post the minimum code that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately, I don't have a specific code snippet to post. As you can see in the stack trace, the line is in the main.m. These crashes started appearing after iOS 9.0. I have updated the AFNetworking package to the latest version in cocoa pods after this error. Hopefully that fixes it. If any of you see the same error please share.